# How to create a jar with an external folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, directory, external

I have a java project with the src folder and another external folder in Eclipse. This works in Eclipse but how can i correctly export these two folders to run the programm without Eclipse?

Comment: Consider using maven, ant, gradle or some other tool for building? Also, Eclipse provides an `export` function (under `File` I think) that will probably do what you need?

Comment: You want to make a JAR file without using eclipse? is that your question??

Comment: please show the structure of your project, especially what's in this external folder - is it source code, or something else?